# CSS Text overflow not working because word-break

Tags: html, css, overflow, word-break

If a write this sentence in a width 90px and height 20px with text overflow property:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Will display:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaa...

The `text-overflow` property will work, but if the sentence is:

> T H I S I S A S E N T E N C E

It will display:

```
T H I S I S A 
S E N T E N C
E
```

The line will break and the `text-overflow` property won't work.

How can I get this to work correctly?

Comment: please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: It isn't JoshC, not here

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLu4h/)